# 12.04-my default python version changed to 2.5

Tags: python

long ago I downloaded and installed python2.5 ( ./configure , make and make install ) in my system.....
now every time I type the command

```
python --version
```

I get

```
Python 2.5.4
```

Is there any way I could return my default python to 2.7????

Answer (score 1):

The way you installed python, it will have been installed in `/usr/local`.

If you want to get rid of the old python:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/python*
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/python2.5
```

If you just want it as non-default: make sure `/usr/local/bin` comes after `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `make uninstall` if you still have the source tree.